# Logstash Extracting fields from 4 different pattern logs into single document

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-grok, elasticsearch-aggregation, grok

I'm having trouble while writing the pattern to extract fields from different events into a single document.

My Logs are like

- **TimeStamp** **LogLevel** - ID:intValue Some Text Service : **MethodName (Which can change)** text **SomeID : intValue**
- TimeStamp LogLevel - ID:intValue SomeText **{JSON}**
- TimeStamp LogLevel - ID:intValue Text **URL** SomeText **KeyValueRequest**
- TimeStamp LogLevel - ID:intValue SomeText **TimeTaken:intValue**
  // ID:intValue is unique for this four log

This are four Different logs/event which I want to add into a single document
But having issues while writing the grok pattern for it

Bold items I want to Store into field of single document in Elasticsearch

If we write pattern for one log it will not work with the another three logs this is where I'm having trouble

Any help is appreciable
Thanks!

Comment: you can put multiple pattern in a single grok filter. Or just use conditionals, so that the correct pattern is applied to the log lines

Answer (score 0):

The thing worked for me is putting multiple pattern in a single grok filter,

grok{
match => { "message"=> [ "Pattern1",

"Pattern2",

"Pattern3",

"Pattern4",

"Pattern5",

"Pattern6"]}
}

**THANKS !**